# Too many include_once/require_once/include/require

Tags: php, include

Due to many included files create an error like instead showing the contents it only shows blank or one of the files has an error like no comma in the end of the script do not shows an error print like fatal error or syntax error in PHP?

I'm a bit worried cause i working on a site right now that has almost 20+ files to include from different directory.

I separated the files like a file that contains the page function, session functions, image function and other more.

I need some advice from anyone. Experts or not experts I really need to know this....

Comment: If you put this at the very top of the page, before everything else, do you see any errors that could be breaking your script?

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

Comment: Sometime when I forgot a ";" on the end of a line nothing will show only a blank page.

Comment: I tried to make simple errors if PHP really shows it but sometimes errors are not show. Basically I am working on the last included files so the files before the last included has no error cause they are just functions and classes but separated by usage.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have error reporting turned off, i am not sure, if this is your question, though ;-). Put

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the very beginning of your script if you want to debug and don't want to change php.ini settings. Debugging like this on a production site is for obvious reasons not recommended, though (every visitor can see the error including sensible information, the error might contain).

It does not matter how many includes you have in your application -- 20 are not much, btw. -- you will always get the error together with the information in which line and which file it occured ...

Comment: I also added that one including the following:ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", true); 
ini_set("display_startup_errors ", true); 
ini_set("html_errors", true);

Comment: Won't all of the potential startup errors have already occurred by the time you call `ini_set` with `display_startup_errors`?