# Which is faster XML or INI?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, include, require

I'm wondering if the XML is faster that INI or vise versa.

I'm developing a site that includes many files this question is connected to my problem [about including many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777522/too-many-include-once-require-once-include-require)
and I decided to take another step on this I want to test ini and xml if the load or process will decrease I mean the site will be faster loader. As far as I know INI is very good on PHP including but I can't do a comparison on XML vs. INI.

Can any expert or not an expert explain me about this two things I'm new with XML?

Comment: Make a simple INI and simple XML that will generate the same structure of data. Compare the different parsing functions with this files and find out.

Comment: Once your site grows (if it happens), you'll notice how your optimization won't do anything. The bottleneck won't be in number of files included or whether you read your configuration from XML or INI file. On the other hand, why would you even have INI or XML files for configuration? Why not create a PHP file in the first place?

Comment: Have you already thought about JSON? That's faster than XML and INI! A Furicane said, you can also create a PHP file and work with [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/function.var-export.php)

Comment: @Furicane because that's hard to maintain, and a configuration file shouldn't be specific to some language. You might want to read it/change it in a universal way later on, without having to re-write your configuration files.

Comment: @ComFreek JSON? seriously? for a configuration file? not maintainable. at all.

Comment: Don't think about problems you don't have. That will only bring you more problems instead, not solving anything.

Comment: @Furicane I tried php many time and check on the speed and memory consumption it seem will php file is under reading it takes an amount(php process: check if php -> compile -> execute) I think a lot on process and consumption.

Comment: @DvirAzulay You practically right I'm using it for configurations.

Comment: @hakre Thank hakre! Its really bothering me cause to many configuration are on this site and separated in any ways like user configuration, admin configuration and site configuration and template configuration. I don't know if it right either.

Comment: @DvirAzulay Why not? If you don't compress it, it is readable! Okay, maybe XML looks a bit nicer but there's more overhead. But actually the speed is irrelevant and it's highly subjective as hakre said below!

Comment: You can only say if something is right or wrong if you run into *concrete* problems. Asking about the "speed" is most often totally irrelevant for the type of coding we do. And it's a highly subjective / relative matter, so you could toss a coin and would have at least a 50% chance to do the right decision. Because you have no criteria to actually decide. Imagine someone here gives you an answer that sounds totally great. Then you follow that. But in the end, it didn't help you because the problems you run into are totally different.

Comment: @DvirAzulay - if you find php configuration file hard to maintain, what are you even doing in using php or developing whatsoever? It's a moot argument to say that <insert format here> is easier to maintain than straight up PHP file that holds configuration. Also navicroel - I am inclined not to believe that your test method was any good, no hard feelings. Parsing ini / xml so PHP can understand it cannot be (by definition) faster than native language constructs. Also, memory consumption? Do you know how big of a file you should have to spend, say, 5 megs of memory?

Comment: @ComFreek, JSON is hardly readable as configuration file. Too much clutter with quotes, commas, brackets... INI is the cleanest, IMO.

Comment: @Furicane, dude, your point makes no sense. Adding a new array element, or strings, is a mess when dealing with a configuration file. It should be simple, universal, that even your Python friend can understand and parse/edit, something that makes sense. Defining huge PHP multi-dimensional arrays as your configuration IS NOT maintainable.

Comment: @DvirAzulay But sections cannot be nested, so what do you do with object like data? Create sections like `[browser_window_tabs]`?

Comment: @DvirAzulay - I'm not your "dude" and 1) there are many ways of specifying configuration options for php besides multidimensional array and 2) if someone already knows Python that postulates they're not braindead and can understand simple naming conventions in a different language. Using XML that's obnoxiously terrible to even look at is NOT maintainable, but hey, we can throw these arguments around the whole day. Point is - PHP file beats ini/xml in terms of performance. If you can't construct it to the point where you and others can understand it - development isn't your niche.

Comment: @Furicane you are making no sense and certainly implying wrong conclusions about developers. Keep rocking on with PHP configuration files and good luck.

Comment: @DvirAzulay I understand that comprehending is an obstacle for many on this planet Earth, but at least be polite enough and read what other people are writing before spouting nonsense. Have fun with maintaining your "configuration" via XML or whatever useless format out there thinking it's "universal", you obviously have 0 clue what you're talking about.

Comment: @Furicane, you are right. PHP is the most universal you can get, because everyone understands it. Also, INI and XML are useless formats. Basically you are right, since INI and XML are not supported by EVERY POSSIBLE application. It's cool to use 5 different configuration files for your web site, the deployer, tools that other developers create in different languages to solve different problems more effectively, and more. Sure, you are right. Now after you know I read what you said, I'll say it again - what you are writing makes no sense. - Also, tell me how INI or XML isn't universal. Thanks.

Comment: @DvirAzulay you apparently didn't understand a single thing I was saying and I'm not going to a flame war with a person who can't even read. Have fun expressing your frustrations somewhere else.

Comment: Enough with the arguments guys. Hakre is right I have many things to do so as far as I read all your comments it would be much better if I'll try first the INI then XML or might do JSON. So thanks guys for the advice/comments/suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to metric that with your concrete application with the data in question. It's hard to say generally.

But as long as you don't even run into a problem, I would use the one you're familiar with. In case this starts to get slow (which you don't even know if it will *ever* happen), you can still learn about XML anyway.

So don't make up your mind about problems you don't have. I'm sure you've got more to do.

Comment: Rather than using the one you are already familiar with, I would recommend using the one that your users are already familiar with.

Comment: @Michael Kay: Who is the user of an appliction? Each author is at first. Then comes maintenance and feature requests.

Answer (score 4):

As INI files are simpler, I imagine parsing them would take slightly less time. That said, XML can easily represent much more complex data structures.

This being true, I imagine anything where the difference in parsing speed is critical would have other problems - they are both probably going to parsed fast enough for all but the most crazy of edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

With small XML files, instantiating the XML parser can take longer than actually parsing the source file. So the answer may depend on whether your application is already using XML for other purposes.