# Should I use YAML for Config Files in a PHP Application?

Tags: php, yaml

I'm currently writing my own PHP Framework (for kicks, not for mission critical stuff) and I'm  trying to add in functionality where the user can set up what databases the framework should use (a primary db and then maybe one or two fallbacks - like sqlite), where certain files are located, etc. Should I use YAML for this? Is there a better approach or a standard practice?

**My Thoughts**

1. YAML is user (non-technical) friendly in terms of readability
2. In order to keep my Framework from requiring non-standard PHP libraries, I'd have to use something like [Symfony YAML](http://components.symfony-project.org/yaml/) in order to parse the file.
3. Isn't Symfony moving away from YAML?
4. I could use a PHP file full of variables but that would make setup of the framework less transparent to the user.

**Update**

I'm cleaning this question up to make it more constructive and to incorporate some of the answers I've gotten.

**Overall Questions I Have**

1. What are the advantages of YAML over other approaches like XML or even an INI file setup?
2. What is a good rule of thumb regarding when to use YAML over those other approaches or vice versa?

Comment: If the configuration is just a list of variables (no nesting or arrays), wouldn't it be easy just to make a single level YAML parser yourself?

Comment: Why you don't use simple ini files? PHP has built-in functions for this.

Comment: This somewhat reminds me on a question earlier: [Which is faster XML or INI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779060/which-is-faster-xml-or-ini/7779129) - Replace "faster" with "better".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## NO

Personal experience. YAML seems a wonderful idea and I loved it and its simplicity. Then I started investing time on it: the very same concept of being able to read it in a language and write in another was very enticing, but... cutting it short, it turned up to be **a mere illusion**, unsubstantiated by facts.

**Every implementation of YAML differs too much from the other ones**.

- Arrays, automatically serialized by one, cannot sometimes be read by another.
- Cross references are supported, but their implementation is really sketchy.

  References are powerful, but:

  - They are quite *limited* for some hardcore application.
  - They represent an *overkill* to most low-end YAML-based projects.

  So, frequently, they are ignored, *and errored upon*, by most parsers.

Summing it up, the standard isn't well set.

There are core concepts that are nice and simple, but the actual standard document is full of details about **features that most people don't want to use and are difficult and expensive to implement**.

There **isn't** a distinction of **levels of compatibility**, like there is in DOM (DOM level 1, DOM level 2, etc) so every parser implementor implements what they feel like to, to the extent they can bear, then they drop it and it's **hard to discern what works and what doesn't**.

### Use Alternatives

- **JSON** if you value the ***cross language data exchange language*** and ***little redundancy*** aspects as the top priority
- **INI** if you value ***performance and backward compatibility*** (*on PHP*,  as `parse_ini_file()` is fast, and there since... always) and ***readability/editability by humans***, instead.

Comment: I'd like to throw out that there are libraries like Spyc library which do a great job of parsing YAML files.

Comment: No mention of plain PHP arrays? Surely they would have the best performance, are very similar to JSON but more flexible, they allow for comments and conditionals, and also permit proper syntax error checking by the PHP parser.

Answer (score 6):

My personal preference is a for a PHP based configuration file.

i know php so to me learning yaml just for the config files is extra work
when you could have a simple config file like this, which in essence is no harder them yaml, and doesn't require a special interpreter library, just include('config.php') and you are away

```
$config = array(
  'database' => array(
      'default' => array(
         'name' => 'dbname',
         'host' => 'localhost',
         'user' => 'username',
         'pass' => 'password'
      )
   )
);
```

then you can reference config settings like this

```
$host = $config['database']['default']['host'];
```

next step is to keep the config file simple, store the minimal amount of config data required, and then use the database to store the rest, and have admin screens for endusers to change settings within your application.

Comment: It's a pretty established tradition, it comes with advantages (you **don't have to take extra care to check visitors in a typical web, application don't get a peek to the configuration**) but I always felt it encourages users to do random hacks in there.

Comment: *addenda*: there's a pretty well established function to export the configuration from an array: it's `var_export()`, you can `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` it if you want to redirect its output to a file.

Comment: @ZJR ...or just set the second paramter of `var_export` to true, which tells it to return the result rather than outputting it.

Answer (score 2):

I have dig bit more for config  file format and found interesting facts for YAML format.

Mainly it have few drawback

1)  It involve installation and configuration of addition PHP library as YAML Module is not coming by default or have to decouple from symphony framework and use it.

2)  Read and Write performance is worst among all config technologies, if compare to  INI, XML, JSON . Taking lots more time read compare to INI file
http://konrness.com/php5/zend_config-benchmark-json-array-ini-xml-yaml/

3)  Readability is not good, compare to INI and XML format. When it became large then difficult to read and manage with humane eyes.

4)  Bit bulky compare to INI and JSON.

So it’s better to use INI format rather than YAML.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a framework, then yes. You will have to end up doing more work on your part, but the goal of a framework is to make things easier for the person developing the application.

> Isn't Symfony moving away from YAML?

No, Symony2 is almost entirely configured by YAML.

Comment: So you recommend using YAML in this case? To allow as user to easily configure parts of the application like databases, file locations, etc.,?

Answer (score 1):

use json **good idea**
for load config file

```
"username" : "root" //in json file 

 $json = file_get_contents('path/to/file');
 $data = json_decode($json);
 $data->username; //print root
```

for write config file

```
$data['username'] = 'root';
```

`if (file_put_contents('path/to/file', json_encode($dat))) {
 echo "<h4 class='alert alert-success'>config updated</h4>";
}`

last thing if you in web root use this .htaccess

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Comment: **IF** that *JSON config file* is in the **public directory** one must take care to configure the server properly not to deliver that specific file to any possible attacker (just by requesting per URL). PHP-based solution might be slightly better approach in regard to security, because it doesn't directly leak the whole config file.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is make an XML file and make a non dependent frontend to modifying the settings in the XML file.

Comment: And in 2011, I see no reason not to do the very same in *json*.
(Gaining in readability, provided we **indent** it)